# Iterating through DataFrame and keeping track of a certain sequence duration

Tags: python, pandas, series

I'd like to figure out how often a negative values occurs and how long that negative price occurs.

**example df**

```
d = {'value': [1,2,-3,-4,-5,6,7,8,-9,-10], 'period':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I checked which rows had negative values. `df['value'] < 0`

I thought I could just iterate through each row, keep a counter for when a negative value occurs and perhaps moving that row to another df, as I would like to save the beginning `period` and ending `period`.

**What I'm currently trying**

```
def count_negatives(df):
    df_negatives = pd.DataFrame(columns=['start','end', 'counter'])
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        counter = 0
        df_negative_index = 0

        while(row['value'] < 0):
            # if its the first one add it to df as start ?
            # grab the last one and add it as end
            #constantly overwrite the counter?
            counter += 1
        #add counter to df row
        df_negatives['counter'] = counter
    return df_negatives
```

Except that gives me an infinite loop I think. If I replace `while` with an `if` I'm stuck comming up with a way to keep track of how long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think better is avoid loops:

```
#compare by < 
a = df['value'].lt(0)
#running sum
b = a.cumsum()
#counter only for negative consecutive values
df['counter'] = b-b.mask(a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   value  period  counter
0      1       1        0
1      2       2        0
2     -3       3        1
3     -4       4        2
4     -5       5        3
5      6       6        0
6      7       7        0
7      8       8        0
8     -9       9        1
9    -10      10        2
```

Or if dont need reset counter :

```
a = df['value'].lt(0)
#repalce values per mask a to 0
df['counter'] = a.cumsum().where(a, 0)
print (df)
   value  period  counter
0      1       1        0
1      2       2        0
2     -3       3        1
3     -4       4        2
4     -5       5        3
5      6       6        0
6      7       7        0
7      8       8        0
8     -9       9        4
9    -10      10        5
```

If want start and end period:

```
#comapre for negative mask
a = df['value'].lt(0)
#inverted mask
b = (~a).cumsum()

#filter only negative rows
c = b[a].reset_index()

#aggregate first and last value per groups
df = (c.groupby('value')['index']
       .agg([('start', 'first'),('end', 'last')])
       .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
   start  end
0      2    4
1      8    9
```

Comment: @pyd - No, it is different. `b` is subtracted by `b.mask(a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)`

Comment: thank you, this works. However, I'm confused with the inverted masked part. That just turns a `true` to a `negative`?

Comment: @nrvaller - reason is I need same values  per negatives rows, so need cumulative sum for positive values  for grouping by it.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to save the beginning period and ending period.

If this is your requirement, you can use `itertools.groupby`. Note also a `period` series is not required, as Pandas provides a natural integer index (beginning at 0) if not explicitly provided.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

d = {'value': [1,2,-3,-4,-5,6,7,8,-9,-10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

ranges = []
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(df['value'][df['value'] < 0].index), lambda x: x[0]-x[1]):
    group = list(map(itemgetter(1), g))
    ranges.append((group[0], group[-1]))

print(ranges)

[(2, 4), (8, 9)]
```

Then, to convert to a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(ranges, columns=['start', 'end'])

print(df)

   start  end
0      2    4
1      8    9
```